# React Router won't actually dispatch to my url with the event handler attatched

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I use this link tag it won't re-route me to url that I set. I did declare the route in my route and if I use a  without the onClick it directs the browser to the route.

```
     <Link to={"/"} className="button btn btn-dark btn-lg" onClick={buttonSub}>
     Submit Information
     </Link>
```

Comment: share the code for `buttonSub()`

Comment: @7iiBob If they `preventDefault()` on a Link/a element, it will prevent navigation. If they want navigation to happen they should not `preventDefault()`.